# React Native ArrowFunction Against normal function (Appstate)

Tags: function, react-native

I am trying to find out the difference between 2 functions. In my
react native app I use an AppState eventlistener to check if the app
is running in the background or foreground (see code below):

```
AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
```

the function looks like this:

```
  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {

      console.log('nextAppState', nextAppState)

      this.setState({
          appState: nextAppState
      });

  };
```

I did not like the way te function is made because in the listener you call it without a parameter
but it the function itself it has a parameter. So I wanted to change this to make it more clear.
This is what is made:

```
  _handleAppStateChange (nextAppState) {

      console.log('nextAppState', nextAppState)

      this.setState({
          appState: nextAppState
      });

  };
```

This works fine the nextAppState is still logged but the setstate does not work anymore
is says that it`s not a function. Can someone explain me why?

And can someone explain me which of both functions is the best to use.

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start using arrow functions, one of the reason why arrow functions were created is for the problem you have mentioned i.e losing `this` in the function context.

So in order for your function to work you need to bind the function to `this`.
In your constructor add this line

```
this._handleAppStateChange = this._handleAppStateChange.bind(this)
```

Or you can replace this function

```
AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
```

to

```
 AppState.addEventListener('change', (nextAppState) => this._handleAppStateChange(nextAppState));
```

Bonus. 
If you need to pass extra parameter other than nextAppState or which is in state. This line wont work

```
 AppState.addEventListener('change', (nextAppState, this.state.someRandmValue) => this._handleAppStateChange(nextAppState, this.state.someRandmValue));
```

As this.state.someRandomValue is undefined since handleAppState wont emit this value instead use this

```
 AppState.addEventListener('change', (nextAppState) => this._handleAppStateChange(nextAppState, this.state.someRandmValue));
```